# Watin: Clicking on a element works in debug mode but not otherwise

Tags: watin

I've below code which basically clicks on a Click event present a table,

```
browser.Frame("f").Element("Table1").Click();
```

it works properly when during debug mode (like if i put a break point and execute it). But, it does not work when i run it in a flow, I've used `SimpleTimer` to wait until `Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut`, but no use.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a timing problem...

Try to check if the element exist before you click on it.

```
 browser.Frame("f").Element("Table1").Exists
```

And then perform your operation...

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Fixed by turning off "IE Enhanced Security Configuration".

[How to turn off IE enhanced security configuration](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-turn-off-ie-enhanced-security-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

WatiN `WaitForCompleteTimeOut` method either waits until some predicate has been fulfilled or the input time has run out. If you're trying to wait for a while before continuing using `Thread.sleep(int time)` would be a better solution. Though you could of course set a predicate to the `Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut` method that will never be fulfilled so the timeout will always be reached.

If you are trying to wait until an operation is finished you should just forget about the `Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut` method. It is run after every WatiN command, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(webElement);
actions.click();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN));
actions.build().perform();
```

Comment: Please provide some context for this code. What does it do exactly?